# Consecutive episode

Tags: spss-modeler

Good afternoon.
I have data like this

```
ID             Indicator
1                0
1                1
1                0
1                1
1                0
1                1
2                0
2                1
2                1
2                1
2                1   
2                1 
2                1
2                1
```

I need to get ID which has at least 4 consecutive indicators =1. In this example I should get ID = 2, since it has 4 consecutive indicators= 1.  Please help me how to do this in SPSS Modeler. Thank you so much for your help. ID 1 has first indicator=0, 2=1, 3=0,4=1, 5=0 , 6=1, ID 2 has first indicator=o, and others all = 1. There are two columns ID and Indicator, ID 1 has 6 rows and 2 has 8 rows.

To be precise: I want to output the ID that has 4 or more indicators set to 1 consecutively.

Answer (score 1):

What you first need as a way to count the number of consecutive `Indicator = 1` records for the same `ID`.
For this, you can use the "Derive" node with the following settings:

- Set the 'Derive as' option to `Count`
- Set the 'Increment when' to `ID = @OFFSET(ID, 1) and INDICATOR = 1`
- Set the 'Increment by' to `1`
- Set the 'Reset when' to `INDICATOR = 0`

[image: Derive as Count]

Following the 'Derive' node, you can then use a 'Select' node to only select the records where the number of consecutive 1's is equal to 4, and finally, use a 'Distinct' node to keep only one record for each `ID`.

I have shared a sample stream that shows the process [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ez5NBiXLMH1JB_bGAzRuZBK8SC3Q7VFH).